# Call any function with any number or type of argument within another function in C

Tags: c, function, telnet

Let's assume that I have the following functions:

```
void func1 (void arg1, int arg2);
int func2 (void arg1, int arg2, char* arg3);
char func3 (char* arg1, int arg2, FIlE* arg3);
.
.
```

I mean, I could have functions that return any type and take any number of arguments of any type.

Now, how could I create a function that takes another function as an argument and returns its result? Something like this:

```
void* func_caller(func* func(args))
{
   return func;
}
```

For more details on this, I want to call these functions over a Telnet socket. I've written a function in my program to establish the connection. Now, I want to call other functions in the program by entering them in the Telnet input.

Let's assume my Telnet function provides a prompt, e.g., ->, and I want to do something like this:

```
-> add(4,5) or -> add 4 5 /* actually i don't care how to write it */
Ans: 9
-> read_log_file()
Ans: reading File....
```

Comment: (1) Parse input --> (2) Validate Input --> (3) Call function based on input (a switch statement or string-to-function map) --> (4) produce output

Comment: Indeed. The correct solution is to have some application-tier protocol on top of Telnet and then execute the relevant functions based on that. When you call to order a pizza, you tell the name of the pizza and then the restaurant knows what you want. You don't tell the restaurant a detailed list of ingredients they should use, starting with flour.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not provide features for calling functions with numbers of parameters and the parameter types determined during program execution, only during program translation. (Some C implementations may provide such features.) Generally, programs that need to call multiple types of functions are implemented by writing code with (at least) one call for each type of function to be supported and dispatching between those calls using `switch` or `if` statements.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I work with VxWorks system which already has this features. I am trying to implement it in RT-Linux.